# Web Application Tests Visualization

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, junit, playback

I'm testing a web application with several functionalities. I didn't develop this application, I'm a mere tester. I'm new to testing and when I started working on it I was given a series a Selenium Tests. These tests are performed by using Selenium IDE on Firefox.
They're very easy to perform in this way, cause you can just record and store variables and run the test.

The problem is that when, for example:
* a web page has a table with 3 rows, I prepare the test for this scenario, it works
* the day after the table has 4 rows so my test doesn't work anymore, 
* Selenium doesn't allow me to make a for-cycle over rows or columns

That's why I thought I could export the several Selenium test to Java 4 Web Driver and import them in Eclipse. In this way I'm able to improve the code, by adding for cycles and other stuff.
I created a project for my test suite, imported the JUnit 4 and Selenium library, ran the suite and everything was alright, no errors. It was great.

**The thing is: how I do I manage to VISUALIZE (or Playback) on Firefox Browser my tests, as I was doing earlier in Selenium IDE?? **

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the tests in Eclipse, it will open a Firefox window and perform the tests just as it would in the IDE.

As for actual test management (i.e starting/stopping tests) you will need to invest in some CI software. TeamCity, Jenkins or something like that will work.

As for picking elements out (the 'find' option in Selenium IDE), this is much more tricky as you've just ditched the IDE and are very new to Selenium. It is, however, easily done.

You can run XPath and CSS queries directly into Firefox's Console (or Firebug, if you wish). Thus, you can still run the same queries you would in the IDE, the only difference is how the results are returned to. Selenium IDE will 'highlight' an element, whereas the console will return it as a DOM object.

If none of the above helps, please go into more detail for what you are requiring, but I've covered what the IDE allows you to do and what are the alternatives.

Comment: Your first sentence is (half) correct.  Eclipse opens a new Firefox Window, but this window is empty during the run time. I don't understand why this happens... I was thinking there's a runner method which I'm not using or not using correctly.

Comment: Can we see your code that you are using? Sounds like that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: As for the rest of your answer (for which I forgot to say thank you in my first comment :) ) I need to get informed about CI software. 

As regards the elements in a web page, in general there's no problem in locating them, the point is that for example today I have a table 2 x 2 where each element has a specific xpath tomorrow this table might have one more row so I will have a 3x2 table, with different order of elements (cause they're placed alphabetically) or randomly so my selenium commands tomorrow will fail.

Comment: That is easily overcome with some extra logic - if you post your current code & some sample HTML of the table (since it's a 3 x 2 table I doubt there is much HTML) we can show you how to overcome it.